# React Leaflet creating multiple maps

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to create a map, but for some reason multiple maps are being displayed. I am not sure what is causing this.

**App.js**:

```js
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
const position = [51.505, -0.09]

function Map() {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={100}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='Some random text'
          url="http://blog.damonpollard.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/GTAV_ATLUS_4096x4096.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div >
  );
}

export default Map;
```

**index.css**:

```css
.leaflet-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[image: Here is how the map looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single (non tiled) image as map, use it as an *Image Overlay* instead of as a Tile Layer.

Comment: ```js
        <ImageOverlay
          attribution="Some text"
          url="http://blog.damonpollard.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/GTAV_ATLUS_4096x4096.png"
          bounds={[[0, 0], [4096, 4096]]}
        />
````

The map isn't displaying anymore. I only see a white screen with the marker.

Comment: With these image bounds, I am guessing your zoom becomes an issue. What if you set zoom to -3 for example?

Comment: Setting the zoom to -1 and adjusting the bounds a bit worked for me. Thanks.